# Why will the bundle homomorphism $\hat{g}:TM\to T^* M$ be bijective if each restriction $\hat{g}:T_p M\to T_p^* M$ is bijective?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The following material is based on Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. Let $g$ be a Riemannian metric on a smooth manifold $M$. We define a bundle homomorphism $\hat{g}:TM\to T^* M$ over $M$ as follows. For each $p\in M$ and each $v\in T_p M$, $\hat{g}(v)$ is the covector in $T_p^* M$ defined by
$$\hat{g}(v)(w)=g_p(v,w)$$
for $w\in T_p M$.

Using some linear algebra, I have been able to show each restriction $\hat{g}:T_p M\to T_p^* M$ is bijective. However, I have no idea why this result will in turn make the bundle homomorphism become bijective. Does anyone get to see this? Thank you.

Comment: A vector bundle is (set-theoretically) the disjoint union of its fibers.

Comment: @Thorgott Thank you. May I assume you are going to employ the following result? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_of_Bijections_with_Disjoint_Domains_and_Codomains_is_Bijection

Comment: In most situations, the usual terminology refers to fiber-by-fiber behavior of a bundle homomorphism, anyhow.